# What is the equivalent of the || JavaScript operator in a shell script?

Tags: shell

I have the following line in my Mac OS `.bash_profile` file:

```
alias server="clear && python -m SimpleHTTPServer \$(portdiscovery)"
```

Where `portdiscovery` is a simple program that outputs one available port.

I would like to have an optional port parameter that when provided would override the call to `portdiscovery`, something like this (which won't work):

```
alias server="clear && python -m SimpleHTTPServer $1 || \$(portdiscovery)"
```

I basically need the behavior of the `||` operator in JavaScript, eg: `var port = userInput || portdiscovery()`

Is there a way to do this in a shell script? If its not possible to achieve this with an one-liner how can I achieve this with a shell function?

My function also doesn't seem to work properly

```
function server {
    clear;

    if [ "$1" == "" ]
    then
        python -m SimpleHTTPServer $(portdiscovery)
    else
        python -m SimpleHTTPServer $1
    fi
}
```

Comment: Aliases are simple text substitution, so `$1` in the alias doesn't refer to the alias's first argument, but to `$1` in the context from which the alias was called.

Comment: BTW, the `function` keyword is something of an antipattern -- it's a needless incompatibility with POSIX sh. Just using `server() { ...` is the better way to define functions.

Comment: Likewise, for compatibility reasons, it's safer to be in the habit of using `if [ "$1" = "" ]` or `if [ -z "$1" ]` than `if [ "$1" == "" ]`; `==` is not a valid string comparison operator in POSIX sh.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @CharlesDuffy - will consider your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
server() {
    clear
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer "${1-$(portdiscovery)}"
}
```

In bash, the syntax `${var-default}` means that if `$var` is unset, `default` is used instead. In this case, the default is the output of the function `portdiscovery`.

I have used the standard syntax for a function rather than bash's `function`-style way.

Testing it out:

```
$ portdiscovery() { echo "port discovery"; }
$ server() { echo "${1-$(portdiscovery)}"; }
$ server
port discovery
$ server 8802
8802
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set the alias then check for $1 and reset if it's set

```
server="clear && python -m SimpleHTTPServer ${1}"
[[ ! $1  ]] && server=$(portdiscovery)
```

EDIT:

set the default first.

```
server=$(portdiscovery)
[[ $1  ]] && server="clear && python -m SimpleHTTPServer ${1}"
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If this does not work please share. It worked with my testing. If this is not good practice, I would like to know..

Comment: it should be turned around - set the default first then check/reset.. so what else?

Comment: You're creating a scalar variable containing a chunk of script, with no instructions on how to actually execute that content; `$server` won't work correctly, as it performs string-splitting and glob expansion but not the prior phases of parsing, and neither will running `server` as a command (since you've defined a variable, not an alias or function). Also, since it contains shell syntax, the only way it could be correctly invoked would use `eval` or an equivalent, inducing security issues.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I can look through my shell scripts to make sure only strings are used in cases where this structure is used.